# How to set expiry of Python script after some date

Tags: python, tkinter

I had wriiten a python script and created GUI using Tkinter.I want to set expiry of my exe that does not load after 30 days of Creation .Is there any possible way to do that?

```
    def program_expired():

        if os.path.exists(launch_date):
            with open(launch_date, 'r') as fileRead:
                time_as_str = fileRead.read()
                print(time_as_str)
                start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_as_str, "%Y_%m_%d")


                expire_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=31)

                if datetime.datetime.now() > expire_date:
                    messagebox.Message("Your tool had expired")

                    sys.exit()

        else:
            main()
    def main():
        root = Tk()

        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


        root.geometry("550x300")
        root.mainloop()
program_expired()
```

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do it. If you got stuck on a part trying, post your code and we will help you out.

Comment: i had updated my question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have your logic setup, but I am not sure if reading from a file is what you intended to do. Here is how to just compare a hard coded date with current date.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime

def program_expired():
    app_date = datetime(year=2019,month=5,day=1) #setup a datetime object
    now = datetime.now()
    if (now-app_date).days >=5: #change to 30
        messagebox.showerror("Error","Your tool had expired")
    else:
        main()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.geometry("550x300")
    root.title("Tool")
    root.mainloop()

program_expired()
```

Note that the user can continue to use your app if they rewind system time to 30 days within your creation date. If so you will need something else, like parsing a time retrieved from Internet.

Comment: datetime will produce local time which still not safe for expiration date. user still able to edit their PC local time

Comment: yeah, I just add more info, sorry